# Using Hyperlink in Access to link to excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-access

I am trying to link a cell in a table in Access to some specific spreadsheets in an Excel workbook.
I used the hyperlink and put the address like this 
`"My%20workbook.xlsx#Sheet12!a1"` ,
it work perfectly, but then my spreadsheet name contain some spaces and special characters like `"-&"` , I modified the address as follow

```
"My%20workbook.xlsx#Sheet 13!a1" 
"My%20workbook.xlsx#'Sheet 13'"
```

It didn't work since Access 2007 auto delelte everything after the single quote.
Is there anyway that I can fix it?
I tried with Microsoft Word and using Hyperlink with the same address `"My%20workbook.xlsx#'Sheet 13'!a1"` it still work perfectly

Comment: >Is there anyway that I can fix it?  Remove spaces & special chars from spreadsheet names

Comment: the problem is that I have about 100 spreadsheets in 1 workbook Excel (those are data form my company). I cann't modify the names manually.

Comment: maybe try the %20 trick for spaces:  "My%20workbook.xlsx#Sheet%2013!a1" - if that works look up the [codes](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/chars.html) for the special chars